# Finding $\delta$ given an $\epsilon >0$ to prove $\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{3 x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove $$\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{3 x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0$$ Using $\epsilon-\delta$ approach.

Given an $\epsilon >0$ we should find  $\delta >0$ such that $$|f(x,y)-0|<\epsilon$$ Whenever $$0<\|(x, y)\|_{2}<\delta$$

Now i started as:
$$\left|\frac{3 x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|<\varepsilon \to (1)$$
Also we have:
$$\left|\frac{3 x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|<3|x|<3 \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \to (2)$$

But how to say from $(1)$ and $(2)$ $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to note that $$0\leq \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq 1,$$and that $|x| \leq \|(x,y)\|$. So, let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $\delta = \epsilon/3$. If $0<\|(x,y)\| < \delta$, then in particular $|x|<\delta$, so $$\left|\frac{3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right| = 3|x|\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq 3|x| < 3\delta  = \epsilon.$$

Comment: how do we know a priori to pick $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$?

Comment: Experience + reverse engineering. I looked at $3xy^2/(x^2+y^2)$, said "the $y^2/(x^2+y^2)$ doesn't matter", hit everything with $|\cdot|$, had just the $3|x|$ left, and then clearly $\delta/3$ works. This all happened in my head, then I wrote it "backwards" above.

Comment: Oops, meant $\epsilon/3$ above, too late to fix it.